# Office for Mac 2016 :: PowerPoint :: Rename Objects

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office-for-mac

How can I rename objects in PowerPoint for Mac 2016, similar to PowerPoint 2016 for Windows? The same window allows you to toggle visibility of individual elements on a slide.

I can't find this window in Office 2016 for Mac, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac Powerpoint lacks the Selection pane that the Windows version includes.

I suspect the only way to do it is via VBA.

```
Sub RenameIt()
   ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = InputBox("New name", "Rename It")
End Sub
```

There's no error trapping there; it's up to the user to make sure something on the slide is selected before running the macro.